# How to review "blog like" posts

Tags: support, review

I just reviewed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716242/outer-angularjs-directive-doesnt-build-inner-directive-correctly) and was unsure how to handle. Should the new answer of OP be attached to the question? The question is already very long and the time span between posting could irritate people.

Especially the `When I find out why it behaves differently I'll post back.` gives a blog like style imo. I think this is not really an answer.

Comment: That question isn't really that long.

Comment: So should I flag the new answer as "not an answer"?

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't really that bad.  In fact, it's better than most; it provides the information needed to answer it, and only that information.

I cleaned it up a bit, and added the Plunker code to it.  I considered merging his answer into the question, but it's not really worth it; it's actually better where it is now.